# rand() in MinGW g++

Tags: c++, c++11, mingw

I have a basic C++ file like so:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    float x = rand();
    cout << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this through g++ on Ubuntu with `g++ test.cpp -o test -std=c++11`, I get no errors, and the program runs just fine. But when I run it through g++ on MinGW with the same command, I get the following error:

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:6:17: error: 'rand' was not declared in this scope
  float x = rand();
                 ^
```

I have GCC version 5.3.0. Attempting to compile with `g++ test.cpp -o test.exe -std=gnu++11` or `g++ test.cpp -o test.exe -std=c++0x` yield the same result.

Comment: Can you try adding <cstdlib>?

Comment: @coderredoc `rand_s()` yields the same result as before. @D_Untouchable including `<cstdlib>` does "work" for `rand()`, but other C++11 functions like `time(NULL)` are still not working correctly. I'm thinking MinGW's C++11 support in its entirety is broken. Once again, `g++11` and `c++0x` give me the same thing.

Comment: Correction: `time(NULL)` is not a C++11 function, but it is definitely not working in MinGW either.

Comment: @Sil.: The problem is header inclusion as mentioned...check the mingw compiler's components

Comment: I am aware of the `rand()` function in <cstdlib>, but it is *not* what I need. I specifically need the `rand()` function to be available in the C++11 standard without including a header that would also make it available in the C++98 standard. In other words, I need g++ to work the same way on both Linux and Windows. That is critical. Is there any way I can install a version of g++ that is a little closer to its Linux counterpart, or would it be a better idea for me to ditch MinGW entirely?

Comment: There is no standard library `rand()` function that satisfies your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You must include library for the random function first

i-e

```
#include < cstdlib >
```

After that your code will work perfectly

Here is the correct code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {
float x = rand();
cout << x << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Some compilers allow you to use random function without including library but standard C++ compilers doesn't allow you. 
Hope this will help you